# Is there a Keras Callback that runs evaluation on the validation data after every N steps or every N batches?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

As stated in the question is there a `tf.keras Callback` that is available or if somebody has written that runs evaluation after every N steps/batches for Tensorflow 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is available in tensorflow2.1 you can visit documentation of tensorflow [Callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback) .

```
on_test_batch_begin(
    batch,
    logs=None
)
```

Called at the beginning of a batch in evaluate methods.

```
on_test_batch_end(
    batch,
    logs=None
)
```

Called at the end of a batch in evaluate methods.

```
on_test_begin(logs=None)
```

Called at the beginning of evaluation or validation.

```
on_test_end(logs=None)
```

Called at the end of evaluation or validation.